# Idiomatic way to pass an array of `OsStr`

Tags: arrays, string, rust, idioms

What is the idiomatic way to pass or represent a `&[&OsStr]`? This way seems to have a lot of unnecessary text:

```
fn foo(file: &OsStr) {
    Command::new("bar")
        .args(&[OsStr::new("baz"), OsStr::new("qux"), file])
        .spawn();
}
```

This way looks cleaner, and is [how it is done in some of the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args). However, the `file.to_str().unwrap()` is distracting, and it is strange to convert an `OsStr` to a `str` just to convert it back to a `OsStr`.

```
fn foo(file: &OsStr) {
    Command::new("bar")
        .args(&["baz", "qux", file.to_str().unwrap()])
        .spawn();
}
```

Is there a third option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your main complaint with the first version is that it is too verbose, here is an attempt to reduce the verbosity using a macro:

```
macro_rules! args {
    ($($a:expr),*) => { 
        &[
            $(<AsRef<OsStr>>::as_ref(&$a),)*
        ]
    }
}


pub fn foo(file: &OsStr) -> Result<Child> {
    Command::new("bar")
        .args(args!["baz", "qux", file])
        .spawn()
}
```

I don't know whether this would be "idiomatic", but that's mostly a matter of preference in cases like this. I personally wouldn't mind the verbosity too much, but maybe slightly shorten the args list to

```
&["baz".as_ref(), "qux".as_ref(), file]
```

Comment: Upvote for your second suggestion, not the first. I think using `as_ref` as in your second example is the idiomatic way to handle this.